# Is it possible to reference values on child object records in Process Builder?

Tags: process-builder, create-records

On the `Case` there is a custom junction object that looks up to the `Account` called `Support_Team__c`. This allows for the association of multiple `Support Team` members to a case. On this junction object, there is also a field to identify the member's `Role` such as, client care manager, field service technician, etc.

I am trying to create a process in Process Builder to create a new `Task` record when a checkbox is set to `true` on the case, and assign it to the `Field Service Technician` on the case's `Support Team`. However, when I attempt to do this, I cannot do a lookup against people on the `Support Team`. I can do lookups against singular values, such as the case `Owner` but cannot do the same for children.

Is this something that can be accomplished with process builder, or is APEX required here?

Comment: You can *probably* just jump over to a Flow to find the right records, and send the email from there. I'd probably use Apex in the interest of saving time, but that's more of a personal preference, I find flows take forever to build.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's what I'll end up doing. Just out of curiosity, I thought that flows were primarily for creating wizards to assist users in going through a process, not so much for automation. Is this understanding incorrect?

Comment: You can do a lot of automation with Flow nowadays, but as sfdcfox says, it takes a long time to build them because the Flash interface is so slow and clunky.

Comment: Looking forward to the new **non-flash** interface coming in the Spring '19 release!!   :)